# Make a callback from a request(options, callback)? Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, request

I've been messing around with callbacks all day & I can't seem to figure out how to call `info` out of `callback`. Im using request.js, & I read that there is a callback property but I don't know how to apply it, any input would be appreciated. Here is the code

```
function add(i, call) {

  var options = {
    url: 'Hidden' + i,
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Token token="Hidden"'
    }
  }

  function callback(error, response, body) {
    var info = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(body), null, 1);
    console.log(info);    
  }

  request(options, callback);
  call(info);
}

function apply(data) {
  console.log(data)
}

add(1, apply);
```

Comment: So could you explain what error's / problem's your getting.?

Comment: @Keith the properties for request require `callback(error, response, body)` so I'm not suite sure how to apply a callback in order to get the variable inside the function, after `request(options, callback);` has run

Comment: Still not sure what your problem is,  request is an async function.. If do you mean after you call add you want it to return the value,.. Then you can't do it that way..  You would need to add a callback to your add function..  But better than that you might want to look into using Promises, as it's very easy to get caught in callback hell when dealing with async functions.

Comment: I've added a callback to my add function, & I still wasn't able to access it. I did `function add(i =1, call)` & in the add function I called `call(info);` & wasn't able to access the value. Am I doing that right

Comment: *"I've added a callback to my add function, & I still wasn't able to access it."* Please post your code. You might want to have a look at [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/218196)

Comment: If you call it like ->  `add(1, function (info) { console.log(info); });`  should work.  Again, you might want to look into promises, as callbacks can become very unmanageable.

Comment: @FelixKling Updated my code

Comment: `info` only exists **inside** `callback`, but you placed `call(info)` **outside** of `callback`. That also means `call(info)` is executed before `callback` is executed. That cannot work. Move `call(info)` **inside** `callback`. I recommend to read a JavaScript tutorial that explains scope, e.g. http://eloquentjavascript.net/03_functions.html#h_u4j2OhpYkg .

Comment: @FelixKling I've moved `call(info)` inside of `callback` & its still not logging anything

Comment: If you don't even see the `console.log(info);` part, then the issue is somewhere else.